# Return result of pgr_dijkstra() in pgrouting 2.2

Tags: pgrouting

I am testing pgr_dijkstra() in pgrouting 2.2, but got columns (seq, id1, id2, cost) in the return result rather than columns (seq, path_seq, node, edge, cost, agg_cost) as described in the pgrouting 2.2 manual. This result is more like that described in the pgrouting 2.0 manual. Any ideas as to why this is happening?

I am using the following configurations under Windows, and this test is for one-to-one routing only:

```
[('PostgreSQL 9.5.2, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit',
  'POSTGIS="2.2.2 r14797" GEOS="3.5.0-CAPI-1.9.0 r4090" PROJ="Rel. 4.9.1, 04 March 2015" GDAL="GDAL 2.0.2, released 2016/01/26" LIBXML="2.7.8" LIBJSON="0.12" RASTER',
  '(2.2.2,pgrouting-2.2.2,544044b,master,1.59.0)')]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the reason --- I had the parameter has_rcost:= true, which apparently caused pgr_dijkstra() to fallback on version 2.0. Removing this parameter and I got results in agreement with the pgrouting 2.2 manual.